# Instantiate object from String with classname and parameters

Tags: scala

I have a trait as follows in scala

```
trait Ingredients
case class Water(temperature: Int, litters: Double) extends Ingredients
```

Also I have a string read from a file with:

```
"Water(temperature=15, litters=50)"
```

I would like to know if it is possible to instantiate an object from this class by passing the String only.

Comment: I encourage you to accept the answer or explain why it isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter's Util-Eval will do this: https://github.com/twitter/util

```
val eval = new Eval
val w = eval[Water]("Water(temperature=15, litters=50)")
```

The evaluated code needs to be a complete unit of Scala code.  Eg, if `Water` is in a package, the package would need to be imported in the evaluated string, or a full package reference would need to be used in the constructor

Comment: Could you give an example? I can't find which part lets me do what i want.

Comment: When I try it all I get is `Compiler exception error: line 1: not found: value Water`

Comment: You probably defined `Water` in a package.  if so, you either need to include the package name in your string `com.mypackage.Water(...)` or else prepend an import statement to the string before executing it.  The string needs to be fully parseable and valid Scala code.